# Try to get automatic WSL2 IP for Xdebug and PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

I configured Xdebug with PhpStorm in a WSL2 Debian instance.

Here is the configuration of my xdebug.ini :

```ini
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=false
xdebug.client_host=${WSL_IP}
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

the line `xdebug.client_host=${WSL_IP}` is in another file : `.bash_aliases`

```bash
export WSL_IP=$(grep -E '^nameserver' /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}')
```

WSL_IP contain the IP of my vEthernet WSL.

In short I used this solution for dynamically get the current IP of WSL every time I reboot my computer.

The main problem is `${WSL_IP}` doesn't return the value at the line `xdebug.client_host=${WSL_IP}`

I even try to write in this way `xdebug.client_host=$(echo $WSL_IP)` but it didn't work.

So my solution was to get the value of `$WSL_IP`
`xdebug.client_host=${WSL_IP}` -> `xdebug.client_host=[IP Value]`

And it works in this way but the problem is every time the WSL IP changes, I have to update the file config in xdebug.ini with the new IP value.

Do you have a solution of why `${WSL_IP}` doesn't work in xdebug.ini?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From Xdebug 3.2 you can use `xdebug://nameserver` as value for `xdebug.client_host` in this situation: https://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00002079

Comment: Interesting to know. Unfortunately I have to use xdebug 3.1. Do you know if there is an alternative for the previous version?

Comment: No, there is not. Why do you have to use an old version?

Comment: For the enterprise where I work. We still have apps with php 7.4 so xdebug version supported to this version of php is 3.1.6.